# Solve $f$ by $f(x)=17+\int_0^x\frac{f(t)}{(t+2)(t+3)}\,dt$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Solve $f(1)$ by $f(x)=17+\int_0^x\frac{f(t)}{(t+2)(t+3)}\,dt$ when $x>0$.

My attempt was to differentiate both side and get $f'(x)=\frac{f(x)}{(x+2)(x+3)}$. However, I can't continue going on. Need help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So $${y'\over y} = {1\over x+2}-{1\over x+3}$$ and thus $$\int {dy\over y} = \int ({1\over x+2}-{1\over x+3})dx$$ which give us: $$\ln y = \ln{x+2\over x+3}+c\implies y=A\cdot {x+2\over x+3}$$

Note that $f(0)= 17$ so $A=51/2$ and thus $f(1) = {3\over 4}\cdot {51\over 2}= ...$

Answer (score 2):

It follows from what you wrote that\begin{align}(\log\circ f)'(x)&=\frac1{(x+2)(x+3)}\\&=\frac1{x+2}-\frac1{x+3}\\&=\log'(x+2)-\log'(x+3).\end{align}Can you take it from here?

Comment: It is better to not write ${\log}^{'}(x)$

Comment: And why not?${}$

Comment: We only define $f^{'}(x)$ as the differentiation of $f(x)$, but we don't $\log^{'}(x)=\frac{d}{dx} (\log x)$

Comment: In my answer, I used the fact that $\log'x=\frac1x$ and that therefore$$\frac1{x+2}-\frac1{x+3}=\log'(x+2)-\log'(x+3).$$Do you see anything wrong with this?

Comment: No, I mean it we don't define $log^{'}x$ is the derivative of $\log x$, ok?

Comment: @IsaacYIUMathStudio I don't understand that sentence.

Comment: This notation is fine. $f'$ represents the derivative of a general function $f$, it even could be $\log$!

Comment: No people would use the notation like this. It is better to use $(\log x)^{'}$

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=17+\int_{0}^{1} \frac{f(t)}{(t+2)(t+3)}dt $$
D.w.r.t $x$, we get
$$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\frac{1}{(x+2)(x+3)}=\frac{1}{(x+2)}-\frac{1}{(x+3)}$$
Integrating we have,
$$f(x)=C\frac{x+2}{x+3}, ~~C=51/2$$

Comment: The third line is wrong. Please check again

Comment: Thanks, it is corrected now.

Answer (score 0):

Use the first part of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. From the first part

$$ f(x) = 17 + \int_0^x \frac{f(t)}{(t + 2)(t + 3)}dt $$

differentiating both sides give

$$ f’(x) = \frac{f(x)}{(x + 2)(x + 3)} $$

divide both sides by $f(x)$

$$ \frac{f’(x)}{f(x)} = \frac{1}{(x + 2)(x + 3)}$$

Partial Fraction Decomposition gives the RHS

$$ \frac{A}{x + 2} + \frac{B}{x + 3} $$

So when $x = -2$, $A = 1$ and when $x = -3$, $B = -1$ and therefore, RHS would be

$$ \frac{f’(x)}{f(x)} = \frac{1}{x + 2} - \frac{1}{x + 3} $$

Now, Integrate both sides with respect to x. Your equation now becomes

$$ \int\frac{f’(x)}{f(x)}dx = \int \frac{1}{x + 2} - \frac{1}{x + 3} dx $$

$$ = ln |f(x)| = ln |x + 2| - ln |x + 3| + C $$

Clean things up

$$ ln|f(x)| = ln\left|\frac{x + 2}{x + 3}\right| + C $$

exponentiating both sides

$$ e^{f(x)} = e^{ln\left|\frac{x + 2}{x + 3}\right| + C} $$

$$ f(x) = \frac{x + 2}{x + 3} C $$

We can say $e^C$ is also equal to $C$ because it’s the same as the constant of integration. Now let us try finding $f(0)$ by relating $f(x)$ into our current equation. In our original equation;

$$f(x) = 17 + \int_0^x \frac{f(t)}{(t + 2)(t + 3)}dt$$

$$\frac{(x + 2)}{(x + 3)}C = \int_0^x\frac{f(t)}{(t + 2)(t + 3)}dt$$

So when $x = 0$ we are left with $17$ alone in the right side of our equation because any integral that contains both limits equal to one another evaluates straightly to zero.

$$f(0) = 17$$
$$\frac{2}{3}C = 17$$
$$C = 17\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)$$
$$C = \frac{51}{2}$$

So, when x = 1

$$ f(1) = \frac{3}{4} C$$
$$ f(1) = \left(\frac{3}{4}\right) \left(\frac{51}{2}\right)$$
$$ f(1) = \frac{153}{8}$$

Comment: Excuse me, then what is the $C$?

Comment: @IsaacYIUMathStudio constant of integration. I had it intentionally carried it all the way.

Comment: However, you can find the constant actually, by substituting $x=0$

Comment: Wouldn’t that give me $\frac{2}{3} + C$? Or, maybe if I tag on a $+C$ on the LHS would eliminate the constant? It wouldn’t make sense right? Because the constant can be any number.

Comment: You are actually calculating wrong. In the step of the 8th to 9th line of the equation, it should be $f(x)=e^C\dfrac{x+2}{x+3}$. Also, you should substitute $x=0$ into the initial equation. Please look the answers upwards

Comment: @IsaacYIUMathStudio oof. Edited already. Man, I’m rusty with FTC already.